# Accessing grains using Salt-ssh in Jinja templates

Tags: salt-stack

I need to access custom grains in my config files using Jinja templating. Here are my files.

```
[root@localhost salt]# cat my_config.conf
{{ grains['ip'] }}

[root@localhost salt]# cat test_jinja.sls
/root/my_config.conf:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://my_config.conf
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: '0644'
    - makedirs: True
    - force: True
    - template: jinja

[root@localhost salt]# salt-ssh 'my-ip' state.sls test_jinja
10.225.253.134:
----------
          ID: /root/test
    Function: file.managed
      Result: False
     Comment: Unable to manage file: Jinja variable 'dict object' has no attribute 'ip'
     Started: 12:57:49.301697
    Duration: 33.039 ms
     Changes:

[root@localhost salt]# cat /etc/salt/roster
my-ip:       # The id to reference the target system with
    host: xx.xx.xx.133       # The IP address or DNS name of the remote host
    user: root        # The user to log in as
    passwd: teledna      # The password to log in with
    grains:
      ip: 'xx.xx.xx.133'
```

How to access the grains in the config files using salt-ssh???

Answer (score 3):

This looks like this is a bug in salt, where the grains from the roster aren't shipped over to the minion, can you try this PR?

https://github.com/saltstack/salt/pull/40775

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that there is no 'ip' grain.
To list all grains use `salt '*' grains.items`

Comment: Do you see this grain in the grains list generated by the command above?

Comment: @RaviShankerReddy It may be a bug - https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/36313. As there described, you can try to use pillar instead of grain.

Comment: It unique for individual servers. So I cant use pillar. I has to be in grains. And also I am not using salt. Its salt-ssh

Comment: @RaviShankerReddy As I told, it is a bug. And you can check grains the same way for salt-ssh.